# Why does the server receive a request, but the client receives a CORS response?

Tags: spring-boot, security, cors, credentials

The server did not allow 'credentials', but the client sent the DELETE request with 'credentials : init' in the http request header.

The deletion logic ran when the data was present in the DB, but the browser actually received a CORS response. A 404 stats response was received when the data did not exist in the DB.

I think we should check whether CORS is possible first and then execute the actual DELETE logic. However, the server informed us that CORS is not possible after executing DELETE logic.

Why does the server receive a request, but the client receives a CORS response?

My Security settings code is as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("*")
            .allowedMethods("OPTIONS", "HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE")
            .allowedHeaders("*");
  }
}
```

The following is the Security Config:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private final JwtProvider jwtProvider;
private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .cors().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthenticationEntryPointImpl());

    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers(CorsUtils::isPreFlightRequest).permitAll()
            ...
```

Answer (score -1):

add a class

```
@Order(-9999)
public class CorsFilter extends HttpFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilter(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String origin = req.getHeader(HttpHeaders.ORIGIN);

        if (StringUtils.hasLength(origin)){
            res.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, origin);
            res.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS, "Origin, x-requested-with, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
            res.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS, "true");
            res.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS, "GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
            res.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_EXPOSE_HEADERS, "Cache-Control, Content-Language, Content-Type, Expires, Last-Modified, Pragma");
            res.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_MAX_AGE, "60");
        }
        super.doFilter(req, res, chain);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't need cookies on my server.
What I'm curious about is not the solution of CORS, but the browser displays CORS, but the reason why the request was successful on the server.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).